# convert neo4j cypher list of integer not working

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have list property [1,2,2,0]. The value is the list default to type of long. To convert to a list of type integer I am using

```
 apoc.convert.toIntList([1,2,2,0])
```

but the result is still a list of type long.....however

```
apoc.convert.toStringList([1,2,2,0])
```

does result in a list of strings. This my query:

```
MERGE (bs:Bslot {date: $date})
ON CREATE 
SET bs.slots = [1,2,2,0]
RETURN   {slots: apoc.convert.toIntList(bs.slots)}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected; see below example:

```
WITH [1,2,2,0.99] as slots
RETURN   {slots: apoc.convert.toIntList(slots)}
```

Result:

```
╒════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"{slots: apoc.convert.toIntList(slots)}"│
╞════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"slots":[1,2,2,0]}                     │
└────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Notice that 0.99 (float) becomes an integer.

In your example; MERGE will not update slots property when that node Bslot with date equals $date. It is because it will only set the value of slots to [1,2,2,0] if that node is new (create).

Comment: I take it you are using the browser!...my query is in NODEJS....the result is different...it's  [{"low":1,"high":0},.....]......and yes only if created the value should be SET...otherwise the existing value is used.

Comment: My temp solution is to use toStringList() and then use parseInt() to convert the array string values to integer....but I would rather do it in the cypher query.

Comment: Then it should be on the neo4j driver that you are using.  In your example; [{"low":1,"high":0},.....] is also integer values (1, 0), so what is your exact example where the list is not integer?

Comment: Yes...it is long integer...so then you have to convert it integer in nodejs if you want to manipulate or display the value. If you try to display as is you will get {object,object.....}. This I understand but in this use case my property is an array on integers but unless I turn off the long integer flag in Neo4j I am going to get an array of objects(long integer). At least this has been my experience....maybe I am missing something.